# Getting internal server error when trying to handle json in django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, post

I'm trying to receive a json object sent from my jquery post call as seen below in the code. I get the "POST OK" callback when the

```
simplejson.loads(request.POST)
```

is commented. But as soon i'm trying do do something with the request I get Internal server error 500. Any ideas or any other ways to handle json?

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def post_post(request):
print 'post_post'
if request.method == 'POST':
    print 'POST'
    messageData = simplejson.load(request.POST)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps("POST OK!"))
else:   
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps("POST NOT OK!"))
```

projectViewModel.js

```
    var m = "Hello World";
        console.log(m);
        $.ajax({
        url: 'postNewPost/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {client_response: JSON.stringify(m)},
         success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                } 
        });
```

Comment: What do your logs say is the problem?

Comment: In your code you've written `simplejson.load` instead of `simplejson.loads`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are trying to pass a dictionary to `loads()` method. `request.POST` is a dictionary with params. You can get raw content using `request.raw_post_data`.

Also `simplejson` is deprecated in Django and if you are using Python 2.6+ you should just use Python `json` package (`import json`)

Also in your js code you passing param `client_response` with json in it. In this case you will need to pass only `request.POST['client_response']` to `loads()` method. But the better way will be to pass json directly.

```
  data: JSON.stringify(m)
```